# How can I convert an undirected graph generated by the Barabasi-Albert model to a directed one?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graph-theory, complex-networks

I have used the Barabasi-Albert model in networkx to generate a graph with n=200 and m=2.
This gives me an undirected graph but I want a directed graph so that I can plot the in and out degree distributions. Would plotting the in and out degrees be possible?

This is my code:

```py
N=200
m=2
G_barabasi=nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n=N,m=m)
```

Comment: you might want to provide a fully reproducible code to generate a sample graph (and provide the expected output)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use the `.to_directed` method on the existing graph:

```py
from networkx import barabasi_albert_graph
G = barabasi_albert_graph(200, 2)
print(G.is_directed())
# False
G_directed = G.to_directed()
print(G_directed.is_directed())
# True
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I wanted to do. Is it possible to attribute random directness so that the in degrees are not equal to the out degree?

Comment: I'm not aware of a built-in method for that, but one hack is to delete or invert a random sample of the edges...